# responsive sprite background image, how to

Tags: css, html

Hi I have two columns of content within a container, the first column has text and the second is a span with a background sprite image. The problem is when I get to smaller screen resolutions, I want the background sprite image to have a width in percentage to be able to scale it along with the H5 with a percentage width, is there a way to do this?

```
h5{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:800px;
}

.sprite{
    background-image: url("assets/img/website_sprite_a.png");
    background-position: -60px -60px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:64px;
}

<div class="container">
 <h5>Title
 </h5>
 <span class="sprite">
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably best not to use a sprite for this. Just use a stand-alone image. Here's a good article on how to do it: http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/11/responsive-background-images-with-fixed-or-fluid-aspect-ratios

Answer (score 4):

In your case I would go with a single `background-image`, but in the case you will have a lot of images or you really want to do this you can use the **background-size** property.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size):

> The background-size CSS property specifies the size of the background images. The size of the image can be fully constrained or only partially in order to preserve its intrinsic ratio.

```
.sprite{
    background-image: url("assets/img/website_sprite_a.png");
    background-position: -30% -30%; //use % instead pixels
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:64px;
    background-size: 100%; //play with this
}
```

You also should read this:

- [Scaling background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Scaling_background_images)

I have played a little bit with this [on JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UFAVH/). Resize the browser to see the effect.

Comment: thanks, I hd a go with that but when I put background-size: 100%; the sprite appears really small, and I don't really want to give the sprite a fixed width.

Comment: @user1937021 Please, provide a jsfiddle with your code to see what is really happening, and you will receive more help (including me)

Answer (score 0):

nearly a year too late, but I was trying to figure out the same and wasn't able to come up with or find a direct  answer. After a little fooling around with multiple pieces of advice, I figured it out. Haven't had a chance to test this on IE8 yet, and stopped bothering with IE6/7, so please bear that in mind.

The trick I found is to use a combination of background-position (using percentages—of the sprite image—as mentioned before), padding-top (again, using percentages—this is the percentage of the total width of the sprite image), and background-size: cover.

Play around with it at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2487a/).

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2e/Sprite_logo.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 50% 0 0 0;
    width: 40%;
}

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="div"></div>
</div>
```